# Reference request: applied ethics and the finance industry

Tags: ethics, reference-request

Have any philosophers written about ethics and the financial services industry?

I'm less interested in the bits covered by law (insider trading, etc) than ethical issues around the role the industry and its members play in society.

Comment: You may like a more general book - "Liars and Outliers: Enabling the Trust that Society needs to Thrive" by Bruce Schneier

Comment: I don't know the general literature in this area, but there's quite a lot about that deals with dangers and disbenefits of usury.   .

Answer (score 0):

Topics relating to morally permissible behaviors of corporations are dealt in the field of business ethics. Finance ethics is a branch in the field. Due to the complexities as it relates to other fields (e.g., laws and accounting), finance ethics has not caught the wild imaginations of philosophers yet, as its paucity in [business ethics entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-business/) in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy testifies. I find the [entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_ethics#Finance) to be far more helpful regarding finance ethics.

Comment: Oddly enough Adam Smith had some interesting views on ethics and finance.